# Appscript Cacheservice function responded for old cache data

Tags: google-apps-script

My Code.gs has following function to filter data according to the username.

**Sign in Function** with Cache.put

```
function signin(obj){
 ...
....
      **var Cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();
      Cache.put('username',f[4])**
      output = true
    }
  })
  return output
}
```

**
Spreadsheet data as per column name**

`

```
function getByName(user, colName = 'userid') {
...........
```

**Next data filter as per username** (Cache.get)

`

```
function getFilteredData() {
  **var Cache = CacheService.getScriptCache();**
  var username = Cache.get('username')
  var values = getByName(username)
  Logger.log(username)
  return values
 }
```

I used **getScriptCache** as above functions
1.When I signed in from first account, I get correct filtered data

2.When I signed in from second account, I get data filtered as in First account. When I refresh and logged in to second account, I get correct filtered data as per second username. What I missed here?`

Comment: Do you want scriptCache or userCache?

Comment: Please consider simplifying your code to an example that we can run...[mcve]

Comment: I used  ` var Cache = CacheService.getScriptCache(); `

Comment: Yes but perhaps you want userCache because it's private to each user